# Register two or more IDbConnection connections in the DI container

Tags: .net, dependency-injection, entity-framework-core

I am using .net6, blazor server and am struggling to register two different instances of IDbConnection in my program.cs.

I am using entityframework core for most connections and use a context factory to register these as follows:

```
 builder.Services.AddDbContextFactory<MyContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(config.GetConnectionString("MyConnection")));
```

I can then consume this in my services by doing the following:

```
    private readonly IDbContextFactory<ChargingContext> _factory;

    public MyRepository(IDbContextFactory<AscRespiteContext> factory)
    {
        _factory = factory;
    }

    public string GetName(int Id)
    {
        using (var context = _factory.CreateDbContext())
        {
            return context.Supplier.Where(x => x.Id == SupplierId).FirstOrDefault().DisplayName;
        }
    }
```

This approach works really well for my EF context stuff, but I also have a requirement to be able to run direct SQL queries in code. To do this, I have created the following in my program.cs.

```
 builder.Services.AddTransient<IDbConnection>((sp) => new SqlConnection(config.GetConnectionString("MyConnection")));
```

In my Service I can use this as follows:

```
    private readonly IDbConnection _storedProcCon;

    public MyRepository(IDbConnection dbConnection)
    {
         _storedProcCon = dbConnection;
    }

    public string GetSomething(int Id)
    {
            DynamicParameters parameters = new DynamicParameters();
            parameters.Add("MyId", Id);
            int Foo = _storedProcCon.QuerySingle<int>("GetAnId", parameters, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
    }
```

My issue is that I can only register one of these IDbConnection connections in program.cs as it isnt bound to a context in the same way as my EF connections. If I add multiple IDbConnections with different connection strings, only the last one that is registered is usable. Is there a way I can 'name' these connections to allow me to register and use more than one?

Many thanks

Comment: You don't need to register connections **at all**. DbContext itself opens connections only when needed, either to read data or persists all pending changes, and closes them immediately afterwards. There's no need for low-level "repository" CRUD classes, in fact these are almost always a smell and actually break EF's concurrency model

Comment: So I should create the connection directly in my repository instead? I would need to register my config values so I can still get to the connection string from the repository though.

Comment: You shouldn't use the "repository" antipattern in the first place. What is the *real* requirement anyway? Whatever it is, the code is wrong and leaks connections. DbContext objects are scoped because *connections* need to be scoped or more specifically, stay alive for as little as possible. Any locks and resources acquired during a connection's or transaction's lifetime remain active until these are closed. ADO.NET and the specific data drivers use connection pooling to eliminate the cost of closing and opening connections.

Comment: The one thing you really need is the connection string, which *is* named. You could create a `ConnectionFactory` service that creates a connection of the appropriate type, using the correct connection string, based on a name. The connection produced by that factory should be used in a `using` block. ADO.NET itself does have [provider factory classes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/obtaining-a-dbproviderfactory) but these are overkill when the only thing you really need is something to create connections

Comment: Primarily we use EF to interact with our database as normal and all of that works just fine. Our additional (and not something we would normally do) requirement is to be able to use Query and QuerySingle to run direct SQL querys to other databases. Primarily it is to handle calling store procedures. I am aware that you can use EF to handle stored procedures, but we simply could not get this to work for us.

Comment: Shouldn't you fix the buggy code instead of assuming it doesn't work? In any case, the code you posted has several smells, including the very use of `IDbContextFactory` just to read a single value. Or the fact it loads an entire object when it only needs a single property. If `MyRepository` is scoped, and `DbContext` is also scoped, there's no need for an IDbContextFactory. Unless you work in an environment like Blazor Server where the scope is the entire user session

Answer (score 0):

If you need to pass a parameter, based on which you need to create a corresponding instance of the class, you can do the following

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddTransient<Func<string, INamedService>>(_ => arg => new NamedService(arg));

var app = builder.Build();

app.MapWhen(_ => true, appBuilder =>
{
    appBuilder.Run(async context =>
    {
        var namedServiceFactory = context.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<Func<string, INamedService>>();
        var firstNamedService = namedServiceFactory("First arg");
        var secondNamedService = namedServiceFactory("Second arg");
        await context.Response.WriteAsync(firstNamedService.GetValue() + " ||| " + secondNamedService.GetValue());
    });
});
app.Run();

public interface INamedService
{
    string GetValue();
}

public class NamedService(string arg): INamedService
{
    public string GetValue() => arg;
}
```